# Python ZeroMQ with multiprocessing loop on calling getpid()

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I have a strange behavior with pyzmq.

I'm using a **`multiprocessing`** module to create two processes with a socket ( **`zmq.REP`** ) for each one. And I'm using the same context ( `zmq.Context()` ).

When I start the script, my CPU is on fire, whereas I'm not doing anything.

So, I checked with `strace -p` and I noticed infinite call of `getpid()` function. Well, I'm not even calling that function in the code.

The code below reproduces that problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import zmq
import multiprocessing

class Worker(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, name, context):

        super(Worker, self).__init__()

        self._name = name
        self._ctx  = context

        self._sock = self._ctx.socket(zmq.REP)

    def run(self):

        while True:

            s = self._sock.recv()
            print s


def main():

    context  = zmq.Context()
    frontend = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
    backend  = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)

    frontend.bind("tcp://*:5555")
    backend.bind("ipc://backend.ipc")

    p = Worker('bar 1', context)
    p.daemon = True
    p.start()

    p = Worker('bar 2', context)
    p.daemon = True
    p.start()

    zmq.proxy(frontend, backend)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Did you ever experience that issue?

Answer (score 0):

Given the statement, the code above reproduces the problem, let me state:

Each call to a **`self._sock.recv( )`** ought produce an error-state of **`EFSM`** or other specific ZeroMQ error response, as the **`_sock`** has not been put into a proper state ( by either a **`.connect()`** nor a **`.bind()`** ), so it cannot serve a call to `.recv()` at all.

As such calls are inside the **`while True:`** and `_sock` does not enter into a blocking-state ( awaiting for a message ), the loop runs at top speed.

### Solution:

setup each socket so as it is established into RTO-state - either by a call to a `.connect( ... )` or `.bind( ... )` and in any case, one ought rather use a **`Poller`** ( with a `.poll(...)` so as to control an amount of time spent in a blocking-state, returning to the main-loop even if there is no message yet.

Comment: You're right, I forgot the `.connect()` call. So I've modified the source and run the test again. I got exactly the same issue. Below the modified source code: `self._sock = self._ctx.socket(zmq.REP) self._sock.connect("ipc://backend.ipc")` So I just add a call to connect just after creating that socket.

Comment: How about adding a **`sleep( 1000 )`** and some diagnosing of the value of `s` + `zmq_errno`?

Comment: In fact, processes wait at `self._sock.recv()` (well I'm not sending anything). So the loop from processes behave correctly but `strace -p` shows something different ( `getpid()`).

Comment: Great, now comment the in the `main()` the SLOC **`# zmq.proxy( frontend, backend )`** & you have isolated the root-cause of the issue.

Comment: hmm...I added the comment but the script end-up and nothing happens. I think that behavior is normal.

Comment: Just check the man page ( https://linux.die.net/man/5/ipc ), how many times is the PID ( in any of it's form and context ) actually involved in any interim step related to the `ipc://` transport-class operations. Apply another transport-class `tcp://` would be the easiest one to do so, to sense the difference. Would you mind to also post the `zmq.__version__` and a brief description of the actual hardware resources' capacities ( CPU-family / #cores / clk [GHz] ) + O/S details?

Comment: Problem solved. `Context()` and `socket()` should be created outside `__init__()`.

Comment: Just for record, the code does not create any `Context` instance in `.__init__()`